Selenium Standalone Chrome Allow Multiple Simultaneous Executions
I have an app that allows users to click a button that performs a webscraping task using selenium. During dev with a webdriver.exe file, this works fine, but we decided to use the selenium/standalone-chrome docker image for production.
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", options=options)
The only issue is that until one user is done with their scraping, the remote Webdriver wont allow connection for another user, whereas when just using the webdriver binary, it will just spin up another process.
My question is, how do I allow multiple users to run these scraping tasks simultaniously.

Is there a way to just make Selenium Grid spin up a new process for each connection?
What about spinning up and destroying docker containers on the fly with a random port number?


You can't dynamically create Docker containers without having unrestricted administrator-level access over the host system.  I'd avoid this as an option if there are other practical alternatives.

These three env variables seem to do the trick
-e SE_NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=10
-e SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=10
-e SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true

So in context
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" -e SE_NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=10 -e SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=10 -e SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

